# Displaying Dictionary in Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I'm returning this response from my server:

```
callback({"City": "Miami", "State": "FL", "Street": "9th Street", "Name": "Big 12", "Zip": "65201", "Lat": -48.219999999999999, "Telephone": "5732168906", "Long": 32.0, "Events": "[{\"End Time\": \"2011-01-22 23:36:31\", \"Name\": \"Margaritas\", \"Start Time\": \"2011-01-22 15:36:31\"}, {\"End Time\": \"2011-01-22 19:36:39\", \"Name\": \"Dollar Bottles\", \"Start Time\": \"2011-01-22 15:36:39\"}, {\"End Time\": \"2011-01-23 23:36:31\", \"Name\": \"All You Can Drink\", \"Start Time\": \"2011-01-23 15:36:31\"}]"})
```

Here is where I'm attempting to parse the response and display it within my "tonight-list".  With **data.Events**,  I get the entire array of dictionaries displayed on screen.

```
function callback(data){
    console.log(data);
    $("#tonight-list").append("<li role='option' tabindex='0' class='ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-c'>Starts:" + 
    data.Events  + 
    "<li>");
```

However, I cannot figure out how to access each element (Start Time, End Time, Name, etc.).  When I try **data.Events[0]**, it gives me just the first character from **data.Events**.

*How do I access each dictionary key in the array of Events?  I just cannot figure out the syntax - it would be nice if I could see all the options on this object type. Thanks for the help in advance!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `Events` in the JSON response a **real array** instead of a **string**, then you can use it like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(reponseText);
var event = obj.Events[0];
alert(event["End Time"]); // hurray
```

**JSON response**

```
callback({
  "City": "Miami",
  "State": "FL",
  "Street": "9th Street",
  "Name": "Big 12",
  "Zip": "65201",
  "Lat": -48.219999999999999,
  "Telephone": "5732168906",
  "Long": 32.0,
  "Events": [{
    "End Time": "2011-01-22 23:36:31",
    "Name": "Margaritas",
    "Start Time": "2011-01-22 15:36:31"
  },
  {
    "End Time": "2011-01-22 19:36:39",
    "Name": "Dollar Bottles",
    "Start Time": "2011-01-22 15:36:39"
  },
  {
    "End Time": "2011-01-23 23:36:31",
    "Name": "All You Can Drink",
    "Start Time": "2011-01-23 15:36:31"
  }]
})​;
```

Comment: Thanks galambalazs!  Changing the first line to **var obj = JSON.parse(data.Events);** made everything work as needed:)

Answer (score 1):

JSON dude! just return valid JSON from your server and use evalJSON. Then you can access each object via their corresponding keys.

edit:

basically do,

data.responseText.evalJSON();

Comment: I knew I needed something along those lines!  Whenever I call data.evalJSON(); it states that object has no evalJSON method.  Do I need to be returning something different from my server? 


content_type='application/javascript; charset=utf-8' is what I'm currently returning.

Comment: application/json or you can return a text response. Either way you need to get the responseText off of the response object.